# Convert specified characters to capitals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to convert the next character after each "_" sign in to capitals?

eg:

```
var myString = "Taylor_swift";
var rg = /(_)/gi;
myString = myString.replace(rg, function(toReplace) {
    $("#textField").val( toReplace.toUpperCase() );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```js
var myString = "Taylor_swift";
var rg = /_(.)/gi;
myString = myString.replace(rg, function(match, toReplace) {
  return ' ' + toReplace.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(myString);
$('#result').html(myString)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That's Arun. But it converts all characters into capitals? I'm looking to convert only the following character after each under score.

Comment: Is it possible to omit the underscore? So the output will look like `Taylor Swift`?

Comment: I had not noticed in the functioning of this response, it's better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom javascript function

```js
function myUpperCase(str) {
  if (str.indexOf("_") >= 0) {
var res = str.split("_");
res[0] = res[0].toUpperCase();
str = res.join("_");
  }
  return str;
}

var myString = "Taylor_swift";
var upCase = myUpperCase(myString);

$("#result").html(upCase);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also:

```js
var txt = "Taylor_swift_more_text".replace(/[^_]+/g, function(a){
   return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1)
}).replace(/_+/g," ");

document.write(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method on the string:

```
myWords = myString.split('_');
myWords[1] = myWords[1].toUpperCase();
```

To capitalize only the first letter, use this:

```
myWords[1] = myWords[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myWords[1].slice(1);
```

Comment: Thanks but it converts all characters to capitals?

Comment: Maybe this would work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript